# php regex_replace stop after first match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to replace the first occurnce of css size(px|pt|em) with -
so this:
`64px 64px #123456`
will become:
`-64px 64px #123456`

I am using the next regex:
`preg_replace("/((-*\d+(?:px|e[mx]|%)?)\s(-*\d+(?:px|e[mx]|%)?)){1,1}?/si", "-$1", $input_lines);`

it works great when there are only 2 sets of sizes but when there are 4 like:
`64px 64px 12px 12px #123456` in get the next results:
`-64px 64px -12px 12px #123456`.
what can I do to stop it after the first occurrence?
Thanks!

Comment: Might I ask why you're modifying a CSS string with JavaScript? This sounds like a very strange use-case.

Comment: @ArunKillu : this not working and as far as I know there is no `g` in preg_replaec    
@FritsvanCampen : I am parsing css files

Comment: don't do that y you want to parse css when browser itself parse for you

Comment: Otherwise if this regexp encounters with a -64px it will modify it to - - 64px...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the 4. argument of preg_replace you can limit how much replace you would like to do:

http://php.net/preg_replace

> limit
>
> ```
> The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to -1 (no limit).
> ```

So you should use this way:

```
preg_replace("/((-*\d+(?:px|e[mx]|%)?)\s(-*\d+(?:px|e[mx]|%)?)){1,1}?/si",
"-$1", $input_lines, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about this argument :-)

Comment: Oops... I've misread a question again. I've just removed my bogus comment.